# how to pass scroll event to parent recyclerview

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, touch-event

how to pass scoll event to parent recyclerview from child recyclerview ?

B recyclerview is child of A recyclerview's itemview.

A is in ViewPager's fragment, the viewpager is under CoordinatorLayout.

the viewpager have

`app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"`

this arrtibute.

when i scroll A , AppbarLayout's offset is change . 
but,.. if i scroll up/down B, then only A scrolled.

this is A recyclerview's itemview

```
<LinearLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical">

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/fold_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/name_project_item"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:text="Medium Text"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:textColor="@color/hip_text"
        android:textSize="14sp" />


    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/create_canvas"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/fab_add">

        </ImageView>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:text="Create Canvas"
            android:textColor="@color/hip_text" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/canvas_recyclerview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

how to pass scoll event to parent recyclerview from child recyclerview ?

sorry to my bad english. please help me T T

Comment: See my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32291057/outer-recyclerview-not-receiving-scroll-events-of-inner-recyclerview

Answer (score 0):

Old post, but I got the exact same problem, resolved by adding in xml RecyclerView:

```
android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false"
```

or in code: (kotlin)

```
recycler.isNestedScrollingEnabled = false
```